# What does en0,en1 etc (en) stand for?

Tags: ui, network

So on Linux it's eth0, eth1 etc which stands for **eth**ernet interface 0 etc

So what does en0 on mac stand for? (the "en" part)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stands for "EtherNet" as far as I know.