# Why would HardwareGrowler show my 'Apple T1 Controller' disconnecting?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

HardwareGrowler just showed me the following notifications on my late-2016 13" MacBook Pro:

- Apple T1 Controller disconnecting.
- Network port en5 disconnecting.

I'm sitting on my couch doing nothing at all. Do I have a hardware fault?

Comment: Isn't en1, en2 etc network related? Seems like a fancy name for a network. [how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-active-network-interfaces-programmatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226871/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-all-active-network-interfaces-programmatically/226880#226880) and [what-does-en0-en1-etc-en-stand-for](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/what-does-en0-en1-etc-en-stand-for)